# Latex alignment for itemize on IEETran

Tags: itemize

I utilize the itemize environment to create a list of notation items with IEEE transactions. However, the border violation of itemize environment annoys me. Could some of you help me fix it? The link for edit is below.

https://www.overleaf.com/9987448856nmfypzfntrgh

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `\def\IEEElabelindentfactori{4.3}` just  before  `\begin{document}`

and     `\raggedright` after `\begin{itemize}`

The alignment will look better if the colon sign `:` is inside the brackets `[...]`

like `\item [$\exists a$ :] exists $a$;`

**Before**

[image: a]

**After**

[image: d]

```
\title{Your Paper}
\author{You}

\def\IEEElabelindentfactori{4.3} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<   

\begin{document}
\maketitle  

\begin{itemize}
\raggedright % added <<<<<<<<<<<<   
\item [$\mathbb{R}$ :] real number set;
\item [$\mathbb{F}^r_{p \times q}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ :] $p \times q$ matrix space of functions derivable until $r^{\text{th}}$-order;
\item [$\mathcal{I}_n$ :] ordered numbered set $\{1, \, \cdots, \, n\}$; 
\item [$\exists a$ :] exists $a$;
\item [$\forall a$ :] for all $a$;
\item [$\rank{(\cdot)}$ :] rank;
\item [$\ker{(\cdot)}$ :] kernel;
\item [$\det{(\cdot)}$ :] determinant;
\item [$\inv{A}$ :] inverse matrix i.e. $\inv{A} \, A = I$ and $A \, \inv{A} = I$;
\item [$\adj{(A)}$ :] adjoint matrix i.e. $\adj{(A)} = \det(A) \, \inv{A}$;
\item [$\numerator(\cdot)$ :] numerator;
\item [$\denominator(\cdot)$ :] denominator;
\item [$A_{m, n}$ :] matrix of $m$ rows and $n$ columns;
\item [$A^{\intercal}$ :] transpose matrix i.e. $\{b_{ij}\}_{i, \, j \in \mathcal{I}_m}$ $\!=\!$ $\{a_{ji}\}_{i, \, j \in \mathcal{I}_m}$;
\item [$\dot{a}$ :] time derivative of $a$;
\item [$\hat{a}$ :] estimation of $a$;
\item [$\tilde{a}$ :] error between $a$ and desired value $a^{\star}$;
\item [$\abs{\cdot}$ :] absolute value;
\item [$\begin{pmatrix} n\\m \end{pmatrix}$ :] binomial coefficients $\frac{n!}{m! \cdot (n-m)!}$;
\item [$\inv{f}(x)$ :] Inverse function i.e. $f(\inv{f}(x)) = x$;
\item [$\mathcal{L}_a b$ :] Lie derivative of distribution $b$ respective to vector field $a$;
\item [$\inf_{\mathcal{X}} (\cdot)$ :] infimum function on space $\mathcal{X}$;
\item [$\sup_{\mathcal{X}} (\cdot)$ :] supremum function on space $\mathcal{X}$;
\item [$\min_{\mathcal{X}} (\cdot)$ :] minimum value on space $\mathcal{X}$;
\item [$\max_{\mathcal{X}} (\cdot)$ :] maximum value on space $\mathcal{X}$;
\item [$\sgn{(\cdot)}$ :] sign function. On this article, 1 to non-negative numbers and -1 otherwise.
\item [$\mathcal{A}$ :] space of variable $a$;
\item [$\mathscr{A}$ :] compact set;
\end{itemize}

\section{Some examples to get started}
```